# table row is getting adjusted within the first column

Tags: html, css, angular

I have the following table:

```html
<div>
  <table class="table-alignment table table-striped">
    <tr class="text text-center">
      <th>Symbol</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Timestamp</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
    <div *ngIf="loading == true" class="loader loader-alignment"></div>
    <div *ngIf="loading == false">
      <tr *ngFor="let s of stats" class="text text-center" [ngClass]="{'text-success' : s.transaction_type=='BUY', 'text-danger' : s.transaction_type=='SELL'}">
        <td>{{s.tradingsymbol | formatSymbol}}</td>
        <td>{{s.filled_quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{s.order_timestamp}}</td>
        <td>{{s.average_price}}</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </table>
</div>
```

The problem here is that the entire tr is rendered in 1st column. How do i fix this?

Comment: you can't have a div inside a table

Comment: You can try `ng-container` instead of `div`. It supports `ngIf` without creating a container in the DOM.

Comment: I think you inserted the div because you cannot add `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` on the same element. you can use `ng-container` instead of the `<div>`

Comment: I will try with ng-container

Comment: ng-container worked fine. Thanks Daniomi and ConnorsFan

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the basic HTML elements `thead` and `tbody`.
Also, for example you don't have to write `loading == false`, write `!loading` instead.

```
<div>
  <table class="table-alignment table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr class="text text-center">
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <div *ngIf="loading" class="loader loader-alignment"></div>
    <tbody *ngIf="!loading">
      <tr *ngFor = "let s of stats" class = "text text-center" [ngClass]="{'text-success' : s.transaction_type=='BUY', 'text-danger' : s.transaction_type=='SELL'}">
        <td>{{s.tradingsymbol | formatSymbol}}</td>
        <td>{{s.filled_quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{s.order_timestamp}}</td>
        <td>{{s.average_price}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```